# Blocking an external bootstrap css file

Tags: css

**How can you block an external css stylesheet (that is loaded no matter what) from applying styles on a website?**

I am using a service for some booking software on a website. This service opens directly on my existing website, in a modal. It is bootstrap's css file, which is completely messing up my styles on the rest of the website. I have no control over this external stylesheet, and I want to avoid having to go through all of my own css to add specificity all over.

Is there a simple way to stop this external stylesheet from applying styles when the modal is not open?

I'm thinking I should find a way to block it, and then load my own version of this file, that applies only when the body has the class "modal-open".

Comment: Not via CSS, no. If you can get hold of the `link` element in the DOM, then you can `disable` it via JS though.

Comment: Can you open it in an `<iframe>` in the modal?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of that. Perfect solution, thanks @04FS!